# SvelteKit build throws ESM module error in production with adapter-node

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sveltekit

exported via `npm run build`

Tested with the standard SvelteKit demo app and addition of adapter-node in the config as per usual:

```
import adapter from '@sveltejs/adapter-node'

const config = {
    kit: {
        // hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html
        target: '#svelte',
        adapter: adapter()
    }
};

export default config;
```

Using the latest versions as of writing this:

- SvelteKit v1.0.0-next.123
- adapter-node v1.0.0-next.32.

`node index.js` **works locally** but is **failing in production**:

````
(node:16609) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
/[...]/build/index.js:40
import { createRequire } from "module";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1025:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1059:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1124:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:816:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:79:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47```
````

Server is running latest NodeJS (v16.4.2).

**What I've tried**

- renaming the build's `index.js` to `index.mjs`
- `"type": "module"` in package.json (as is the default now)
- importing `require` in the config like so

```
import { createRequire } from 'module';
const require = createRequire(import.meta.url);

const adapter = require('@sveltejs/adapter-static');
```

Error is persisting. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**
node_modules were not installed correctly previously. Had to make sure that `npm install` was completing correctly on the server. In case this helps someone…

Comment: In my case I had to move the dependency from devDependencies to dependencies in the package.json

Comment: How did you check that `npm install` was completing correctly? Mine didn't throw up errors. I think my issue is that my public server is running on Phusion Passenger, and there's no way of getting round the problem with using `import`. I can try to rebuilt using `require()` instead, or somehow find a way for SvelteKit to build using `.mjs` files, as that does seem to help until I get to a file that isn't and `.mjs` - obviously don't want to change every file in the build manually...

Comment: @e741af0d41bc74bf854041f1fbdbf what exactly did you move from devDependencies to dependencies?

Comment: @MikeyB I don't remember which dependency but the one that was causing the issue. I may have seen which one it was in the error message, or try all the likely dependencies to fail one by one.